# iPhone:What is the use of Airplay SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, airplay

Can someone explain me what is Airplay SDK and when it is used, how to use in program etc. details? I hope, it is used for streaming videos from iPhone to TV?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AirPlay SDK](https://www.airplaysdk.com) is actually a cross-platform game development framework for iPhone/Android/Symbian which is now called **[marmelade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/)**.

AirPlay is also a video & audio streaming technology by Apple and has nothing to do with marmelade. As of iOS 4.3, third-party apps may also send compatible audio and video streams over AirPlay.

Comment: Can you explain what is the first one you are saying AirPlay is marmelade? And then the second point you are saying, it is nothing to do marmelade? Are you meaning, there are two names as AirPlay, one is cross-platform sdk provided by some third party and other is from Apple, which can be used for iOS device videos streaming? I want to study and work on the Apple's Airplay, can you provide me links related to that?

Comment: forget about marmelade, it is sth. completely different. now for Apple's AirPlay: if you want to use it in your app, just set allowsAirPlay property to YES. Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010567-SW2

Comment: Hi, Thats great help! Thank you! Just a last question, if i enable this property in my iPhone app, how can i test it with Apple TV, to know how it is working etc.?

Comment: When the video player shows that AirPlay icon, you know its working. AirPlay capable devices like Apple TV are discovered automatically. The icon also shows up, when a bluetooth headset is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Airplay is used to stream audio and video to other Apple devices. For instance, you can stream a video in an application to a TV via an AppleTV or an iPad or another Apple device. There are some non-Apple devices that can utilize Airplay as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Can you give me the links where i can study more about it?