# Live video streaming using Airplay iphone sdk

Tags: ios, video-streaming, ios5, airplay

I want to stream live video using airplay.To apple device.I searched on net cant find any helpful sample for that.Can any one have idea for it, please share it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to build an app to do this?

Comment: ya i want to live stream iphone to apple device through airplay

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really need,..Go through this [link](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/airplay.htm) . Probably [Airplaykit](https://github.com/rothacr/AirplayKit) might help you.

**EDIT**

Considering your need to develop an app, these links should help..

1. [Complete description and tutorial on Airplay](http://maniacdev.com/game-engine-guide/airplay-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/)
2. [More information on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391231/iphonewhat-is-the-use-of-airplay-sdk)
3. [And this too](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_airplay/)

Comment: i want to live stream iphone to apple device through airplay

Comment: using Airplay kit we cant do live streaming and mirroring.If can please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Take a look at Wowza live streaming!!- http://www.wowza.com/lp2?utm_campaign=PPC+ISM+-+Brand+-+Asia%2FAustralia&utm_medium=ppc&utm_source=ppc&gclid=CIPvw4T-vbkCFSQ44godtmsA8Q hope this helps..